# Why do TikZ Bézier curves print as rectangles when part of a closed path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, printing, ps

When we compile this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Some variants of closing the path
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0) ;
    \coordinate (b) at (2,0) ; 
    \draw[] (a) .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,1) .. (b) -- (a);

    \coordinate (c) at (3,0) ;
    \coordinate (d) at (5,0) ; 
    \draw[] (c) .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,1) .. (d) -- cycle;

    \coordinate (e) at (6,0) ;
    \coordinate (f) at (8,0) ; 
    \draw[] (e) .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,1) .. (f) -- (e) -- cycle;

    % Without closing the path
    \coordinate (g) at (0,-1) ;
    \coordinate (h) at (2,-1) ; 
    \draw[] (g) .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,1) .. (h);

    \coordinate (i) at (3,-1) ;
    \coordinate (j) at (5,-1) ; 
    \draw[] (i) .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,1) .. (j) 
            (j) -- (i);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output we expect and get using `pdflatex` (TeXLive 2014, TikZ 3.0.0):

[image]

When we print the PDF, however, we get this:

[image]

The same happens when converting the PDF with `pdftops` (that is how I obtained the image).

We would certainly expect Bézier curves to print in all cases. What happens here and how do we work around or fix this?

Comment: I've not tried to print it, but compiled with pdflatex (MikTeX) and converted to ps with `pdf2ps`, the result is correct.

Comment: Looks like a driver or PDF viewer problem though. That's very interesting to see.

Comment: My viewer is Evince; should I experiment more with different viewers? Since `pdftops` and `pdf2ps` are not the same thing (afaik) I'll try the latter tomorrow.

Comment: When I compile to PDF and convert to PS with Acrobat, there is no error too. And pdf2ps is ok, like for Ignasi. (I use MikTeX 2.9)

Comment: Using TeXLive 2014 I can replicate the problem when viewing a postscript file generated using `pdftops` with both `evince` and `gv`. However, `pdf2ps` produces a postscript file which renders correctly in both viewers.

Comment: I get the same results as @MarkWibrow except that my viewer is Okular. `pdftops` is provided by `poppler` (at least on my system) while `pdf2ps` is part of `ghostscript`. Something to do with the `cairo` dependency?

Comment: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87254

Comment: Thanks everybody, it seems indeed plausible that this is not a LaTeX-issue after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments above, I have confirmed that `pdf2ps` produces correct PS files. Therefore, `pdftops` seems to have a bug, which [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) [has reported](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87254).

Comment: I'm on poppler/pdftops 0.24.5 while the latest stable release is 0.31.0. The bug cfr reported has not been marked as fixed, but I can not say for sure that it persists in newer versions.